# maven-javadoc-plugin failing in teamcity but works in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, teamcity

We are migrating to teamcity from jenkins. We have maven based projects which run in build. For certain projects we are using maven-javadoc-plugin.

Plugin works fine in jenkins but fails in teamcity with below error:

```
[com.cycorax.ui:ui-mvp-widgets] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1:jar (attach-javadocs) on project ui-mvp-widgets: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1:jar: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.1
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Can someone assist?

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using?

Comment: worked, i just retried.